# C#.net lock object in one mthod and no lock in another method

Tags: c#, object, static, locking

I have two method  “ExecuteNoQuery” (performs dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()) and “Query” performs (dbCommand.ExecuteReader()). 
Both the methods are using same connection object. In ExecuteNoQuery method a lock is implemented(using connection object) and Query method implemented with out lock. In case of multiple thred, different thread accessing both the method simultaneously then what will happen?

Note: In Query method custom connection pooling is implemented with the same object.

```
public int ExecuteNoQuery(string sqlquery, Hashtable htData) {
try {
 lock(Myservice.dbcon)  
  {
    using (OracleCommand dbCommand = new OracleCommand(sqlquery, Myservice.dbcon)) 
        {

              int rowCount = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
              return 1;
        }
  }
}


public OracleDataReader Query(string sqlquery, Hashtable htData)
    {
        try
        {
            OracleDataReader dbReader = null;
            Random ran = new Random();
            int randomnumber = ran.Next(1,5);

           Myservice.dbcon = (OracleConnection) Myservice.htdbcon
           ["Connection_" +randomnumber];

            if (Myservice.dbcon.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Executing 
              || Myservice.dbcon !=  System.Data.ConnectionState.Fetching)
                {
                    using (OracleCommand dbCommand = new OracleCommand(sqlquery,
                     Myservice.dbcon))
                    { 

                        dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    }
                }
                return dbReader;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Both the methods are using same connection object.

Since one method uses a lock and the other does not: bad things. No guarantees are made by the object for this scenario, so you should expect it to fail in interesting ways. You should use the same lock object from both places, or better: only use a connection in isolated code, not a shared connection. With connection pooling, it is very rarely useful to have a shared connection object somewhere. A far more suitable pattern is usually to obtain a connection *when you need it*, and then dispose it. If the underlying provider supports pooling, this will perform ideally, without any issues of synchronization, and will allow parallel queries etc. For example:

```
using (var conn = SomeUtilityClass.GetOpenConnection())
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) 
{
    cmd.CommandText = sqlquery;
    int rowCount = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return 1;
}
```

and, importantly, *do the same* from the `Query` method; no locks, no global shared connections.

I'd also be concerned by the lack of parameters, btw. That suggests you are opening yourself up to SQL injection errors.

Comment: very rarely my application getting a hang situation. when analyzed log i found that the hang is due to simultaneous access of both the method. it wont give any exception(C# / Oracle). any idea what could be the reason for a hang?

Comment: @user2075249 because you have **used it incorrectly** by letting two threads use the connection at once. Part of the most vexing thing with threading issues is that they don't show immediately and always - only when the invalid usage causes a problem such as corrupting internal state of fields, sending incorrectly interleaved data down a socket that should be framed, or reading data back incorrectly. Basically what you are doing ***is wrong***. You must stop using a connection from multiple threads at once.